# python code for counting characters from sequence file

Tags: python

Please I am working in a DNA sequence file and I want to count two successive characters in python I am trying to define a variable and set the value to this two characters

but it doesn't work it gives me zero and this is my code and output

```
y = open('q6.seq' , 'r')
y.readline()
y= open('q6.seq' , 'r')

g=0;
a=0;
c=0;
t=0;
gc=0;
for line in y.readline():

for char in line:
    if char == 'a':
        a+=1

    elif char=='c':
        c+=1

    elif char=='g':
        g+=1
    elif char=='t':
        t+=1
    elif char=='gc':
        gc+=1

print ("a =" + str(a) )
print ("g =" + str(g) )

print ("c =" + str(c) )

print ("t =" + str(t) )
print ("gc =" + str(gc))
```

Comment: `for char in line` loops over _individual_ characters.

Comment: I understand this but if I want to count to successive characters what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by 'successive'? so let's  say you have the line: AAABABAA. What should be the count for A and for B?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but we still don't really understand what you really want.

Comment: Why do you open the file twice?

Comment: I want to count AA for example

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: OK. You want to count 2 for 'AA' but what happens in the case of 'AABAAA'?

Comment: Your code can be shorter. Consider `line.count('A')` for example. Or the `Counter` class in collections.

Comment: ... and what about `'AAAA'`. Should that be 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: No, in the case of this example i want the output says that AA = 2
because its repeated in this whole example two times

Comment: And what about `'AAAAA'`? 2 or 3?

Comment: it should be 2 Elmex80s

Comment: Don't forget to close you file: `y.close()`.

Comment: Done editing my code

Comment: You still open your **q6.seq** file 2 times for `y`. No indent. I do not see the `.count` I suggested.

Comment: I do it and nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `line.count('AA')` to count succeeding characters according to the rules you gave.

Comment: It says '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: @AhmedKhaled then convert `line` to a string. I expect DNA sequences were written as strings. `str(line)` might do it.

Comment: @AhmedKhaled You write `y = open('q6.seq' , 'r')` two times. Just write it only once.

Comment: When i open the file once it doesn't make any count

Comment: @AhmedKhaled Write this `for line in y.readline(): print str(line)`.

Comment: It gives me zero

Comment: @AhmedKhaled Did you changed your code to this `for line in y.readline(): # Do something`?

Comment: Yes i change the loop and it gives me the same result and zero for the consequence characters

Comment: @AhmedKhaled In that case update your code in the question and I will have a quick look.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do, assuming you data is always of this format:

**BUT WE NEED YOU TO SHOW US WHAT THE FILE LOOKS LIKE**

```
from collections import defaultdict

sequence = defaultdict.fromkeys(('g', 'a', 'c', 't', 'gc'), 0)

for line in f:
    symbol, val = line.split(' = ')
    sequence[symbol] += int(val)
```